In flutter app I am getting Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000
After adding data to local database sqflite. I keep getting this Warning:

database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use
the transaction object for database operations during a transaction.

And application is not working smoothly.
  class DBHelper {
       static Database? _db;
       Future<Database?> get db async {
         if (_db != null) return _db;
         _db = await initDatabase();
          return _db;
      }  
   
      Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
         io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
         String path = join(documentDirectory.path,"cart.db");
         var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
         return db;
      }

    Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE cart (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,user_id INTEGER ,item_id 
           INTEGER,main_item_id INTEGER,name TEXT,price REAL, qty INTEGER, type TEXT, image 
           TEXT, created_at TEXT, updated_at TEXT )');
    }
  
  // Insert a cart item
  Future<getMyCart> insert(getMyCart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient!.insert('cart', cart.toJson());
    return cart;
  }
  
  // Retrieve the list of cart items
  Future<List<getMyCart>> getCartList() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult =
        await dbClient!.query('cart');
    return queryResult.map((e) => getMyCart.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
  
  // Delete a cart item by id
  Future<int> delete(int? id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient!.delete('cart', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }
  
  // Delete all cart items
  Future<void> deleteAll() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient!.delete('cart');
  }
  
  // Update the quantity of a cart item
  Future<int> updateQuantity(getMyCart cart) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient!
        .update('cart', cart.toJson(), where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [cart.id]);
  }

  // Check if an item exists in the cart
  Future<bool> itemExists(id) async {
    var result = await _db!.rawQuery(
      'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cart WHERE item_id="$id")',
    );
    int? exists = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
    return exists == 1;
  }

  Future<bool> itemExist(id) async {
    dynamic result;
    int? exists;
    if (_db != null) {
      result = await _db!.rawQuery(
        'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cart WHERE item_id="$id")',
      );
      exists = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
    } else {
      exists = 0;
    }
    return exists == 1;
  }

Onclick of Buyonce button I am adding data to local database. Code onClick of  Buyonce button is as given below: -
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              if (getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                      .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                      .item![index]
                      .addonAdded ==
                  1) {
                if (!itemCountMap.containsKey(
                    getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                        .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                        .item![index]
                        .id)) {
                  itemCountMap[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                      .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                      .item![index]
                      .id] = 1;
                }
                await showBottomSheet(
                        context,
                        getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                            .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                            .item![index],
                        itemCountMap[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                                    .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                                    .item![index]
                                    .id] ==
                                0
                            ? 1
                            : itemCountMap[
                                getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                                    .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                                    .item![index]
                                    .id],
                        false)
                    .then((onVal) async {
                  if (onVal != null) {
                    await cart.getData().then((cartItemList) {
                      if (cartItemList.isNotEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          myCartList = cartItemList;
                          itemCountMap[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .id] = onVal;
                          updateCount();
                          isbuynowclicked = selecteditemindex;
                          selecteditemindex = index;
                        });
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
                if (itemCountMap[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                        .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                        .item![index]
                        .id] ==
                    0) {
                  itemCountMap[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                      .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                      .item![index]
                      .id] = 1;
                }
                buynowClicked[getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                    .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                    .item![index]
                    .id] = true;
                selecteditemindex = index;
                isbuynowclicked = selecteditemindex;
              } else {
                bool isItemExist = await dbHelper.itemExists(
                    getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                        .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                        .item![index]
                        .id);
                if (isiteminCart == false && isItemExist == false) {
                  await dbHelper
                      .insert(my_cart_model.getMyCart(
                          id: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .id,
                          userId: globalCurrentUserData.id,
                          itemId: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .id,
                          name: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .name,
                          price: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .offerPrice,
                          qty: 1,
                          type: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .type,
                          image: getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                              .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                              .item![index]
                              .image,
                          createdAt: DateTime.now().toString(),
                          updatedAt: DateTime.now().toString()))
                      .then((result) async {
                    await cart.getData().then((cartItemList) {
                      if (cartItemList.isNotEmpty) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cartItemList.length; i++) {
                          if (cartItemList[i].itemId ==
                              getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                                  .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                                  .item![index]
                                  .id) {
                            setState(() {
                              buynowClicked[
                                  getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                                      .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                                      .item![index]
                                      .id] = true;
                              selecteditemindex = index;
                              itemCountMap[
                                  getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                                      .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                                      .item![index]
                                      .id] = cartItemList[i].qty!;
                              isbuynowclicked = selecteditemindex;
                              myCartList = cartItemList;
                              updateCount();
                            });
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            child: (cartobj.itemId ==
                    getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                        .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                        .item![index]
                        .id)
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    child: counterContainer(
                        index,
                        getcategoryList[selectedCategoryIndex]
                            .subCategory![selectedSubcategoryIndex]
                            .item![index],
                        cartobj,
                        cart),
                  )
                : Container(
                    width: 100.w, //100,//155,
                    height: 40.h, //37,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10 //6 //3
                          ),
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(49, 164, 113, 1),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        buynowBtnText,
                        style: GoogleFonts.metrophobic(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(49, 164, 113, 1),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          ),

